# Perl Date conversion with Perl's built-in functions

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have a date in the following format which is how it is stored in an external application

```
06/12/2014 6:31 PM IST
```

I want to change this format to which needs to check AM and PM also and rest of the minutes to be hardcoded as `:00+5:30`

```
2014-06-12 18:31:00+05:30
```

Since it is not a simple GMT to PDT change I tried with epoch, but the problem here is that the date is in different format.

Answer (score 2):

you can just do it with regex and a printf. in your particular case i suggest:

```
my $yourstring = '06/12/2014 6:31 PM IST';
my ($mm,$dd,$yy,$hh,$mi,$ampm) = $yourstring =~ m~(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)\s+(AM|PM)\s+~;
if ($ampm eq 'PM' && $hh < 12) { $hh += 12 }
printf ('%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:00+05:30', $yy, $mm, $dd, $hh, $mi);
```

or look into [DateTime::Format::DateParse](http://search.cpan.org/~jhoblitt/DateTime-Format-DateParse-0.05/lib/DateTime/Format/DateParse.pod)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to use Perl's now built in Date/Time functions in [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time%3a%3aPiece.html). Once you convert your time into a true Perl time, you can format it any way you please.

The problem is that Time::Piece doesn't do a very good job at handling timezones. The easiest way of handling timezones on strings is to simply remove them:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

# This is what you have given
my $input_time="6/12/2014 6:31 PM IDT";

# Remove timezone (the last four characters)
my $munged_time = substr $input_time, 0, -4;

# This is a description of your "format" above
# You can find this by doing a "man date" on Unix.
# Sometimes it's "man strftime".
#
# The various %x are bits that represent the time
# in various formats.
# %m = month         %d = month date   %Y = four digit year
# %I = hour 01-12    %M = Minutes      %p = AM/PM  
my $time_format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p";

# Now convert the time from the format to a Time::Zone
# Date Object.
my $time = Time::Piece->strptime($munged_time, $time_format);

# Now that the time is in a Time::Piece object, we can easily
# manipulate it to do whatever we want. We could add or subtract
# date times from each other, add or subtract hours, months, etc.

# Here, I'm just printing out the various bits and pieces of
# "datetime" that I am interested in. Note I'm using time->second
# even though I never specified seconds. It's okay, Time::Piece
# simply assumes that seconds are zero.
#
printf "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d+05:30\n",
    $time->year, $time->mon, $time->mday,
    $time->hour, $time->minute, $time->second;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question does not contain any information about which time formats are possible at all. Are day of month and month always with 2 digits? Is the hour in range 0 to 9 always without a leading 0? Is it possible that the minutes 0 to 9 are without a leading 0? Which time zones are possible, just **IST** or others as well?

Here is a list of Perl regular expression search and replace strings which must be applied all to reformat date and time strings for time zone **IST** to get the date and time in format YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:00+05:30

Reformat all times with **AM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +([01]?\d:[0-5]?\d) AM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 $4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **12:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +(12:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 $4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **01:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?1(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 13$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **02:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?2(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 14$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **03:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?3(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 15$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **04:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?4(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 16$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **05:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?5(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 17$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **06:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?6(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 18$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **07:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?7(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 19$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **08:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?8(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 20$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **09:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +0?9(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 21$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **10:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +10(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 22$4:00+05:30`

Reformat all times with **11:xx PM** in string.

Search: `([01]?\d)/([0-3]?\d)/([12][09]\d\d) +11(:[0-5]?\d) PM IST`
Replace: `$3-$1-$2 23$4:00+05:30`

Insert leading 0 where missing in date (month, day of month) or time (hour, minute) string using an expression with a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead:

Search: `(?<=[ \-:])(\d)(?=[ \-:])`
Replace: `0$1`

In case of above expression does not work because of lookbehind/lookahead, it would be also possible to use less restrictive regular expression:

Search: `\b(\d)\b`
Replace: `0$1`